# Chrome Extension Autoupdate to all users

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Maybe it's a noob question but I just want to ask the method on how to update the extensions to all the users of my extension without re-installing their's. Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: you have the extension published in Web Store?

Comment: @Xan - Yes, I already published it in Web Store using Chrome dashboard. but the client still needs to manually update in order for them to get the new copy.

Comment: Then what is your question? How to speed up updating? Because if you do push an update to a CWS-hosted extension, it will eventually update automatically (it's just that Chrome only polls for extension updates once every few hours)

Comment: My question is how to autoupdate the copies of all the users after I update on Dashboard. They didn't get my updates even after an hour unless they will go to Extensions tab to manually update.